# Seeing hotkeys in menu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, menu

I recently upgraded 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS and having trouble with seeing the hotkeys.

For example if I am in thunderbird and go with the mouse to the file menu on top. In 14.04 it was possible to see the corresponding hotkeys for each action, making it easy to learn e.g. the hotkey for "file -> send now".

It seems that 16.04 does not display the corresponding hotkeys anymore. How can I reenable this?